# Why does ASP.NET publish my local folder paths?

Tags: asp.net

In a common ASP.NET Web Forms page, I specify the location of a backup file as follows:

```
string backupFilePath = "../data/backups";

ICronjobTask[] tasks = new ICronjobTask[]
{
    new FileBackupCronjobTask(backupFilePath)
};
```

The `ICronjobTask` is executed later on. When calling the published page on my web server, an error message tells me that parts of the path `"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\data\backups\file.txt` could not be found.

Why does ASP.NET publish my local directory structure? How do I turn this off?

Comment: What `Target Location` have you specified for you publish command?  My guess is that `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv` exists (on whichever machine you published too), but one or both of the specified sub-directories do not.

Comment: I deploy my ASP.NET (MVC) application via the built-in FTP deploy function. The target location is set to the folder that is defined an ASP.NET MVC application which is running perfectly fine – except for the fact that I don't know how to access the data folder located one directory upwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the `Server.MapPath(string path)` method that returns the physical path corresponding to the specified logical one.

Answer (score 0):

You're displaying the raw exception error message, is my guess. Whenever you do that, you risk giving away information that you don't want to be made public. Instead of doing that, you should interpret the exception and give general information to the user.